# Bootstrap grid doesn't adjust width correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I've a Bootstrap Grid on my website. It includes data from my database. Every input has different number of characters. 
I would like to have a regular arrangement for each dataset (preferably like in case 3). But as you can see in the [attached img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpKFc.png), the boxes have different widths, although I've set the bootstrap-class to "col-xs-12".

Where's the error?

```css
div #datenbank_ausgabe_name_city {
 font-family: Courier New;
 font-size: 20px;
 border: 2px solid red;
}

#datenbank_ausgabe_name_city p {
 float: right;
}


#datenbank_ausgabe_text {
 float: left;
 font-family: Courier New;
 font-size: 40px;
 border: 2px solid red;
 width: 100%;
}

.rahmen {
 border: 2px black solid;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-8">
        <h1>Hallo</h1>
  
  
  <!-- D A T E N B A N K A B F R A G E -->
  


 <div id="datenbank_ausgabe_text" class="col-xs-12"> <?php echo $zeile['text']; ?> </div>
    <div id="datenbank_ausgabe_name_city" class="col-xs-12">
    <p>- 
     <?php echo $zeile['name']; ?>, 
     <?php 
      if($zeile['city_id'] == '1') {
       echo "Miami";
      }
      else if ($zeile['city_id'] == '2') {
       echo "Las Vegas";
      } 
      else if ($zeile['city_id'] == '3') {
       echo "New York";
      }
     ?>
    </p>
    </div> <!-- div hinzugefügt -->   
   <div> </br> </div>   
   </div>
   <?php
     }
   ?>
  </div>

  <?php 
   mysqli_free_result( $db_erg );
  ?>
  
  
  <!-- DATENBANKABFRAGE  E N D E -->
  

  
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2"></div>
 </div>
```

Thanks, Jonas

Comment: can you add the static values without php

Comment: Ah I've got it: just added `div {width: 100%;}` in CSS